# Unable to find the executable

Tags: ros, nodes, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying a run  a node on the terminal using the command **rosrun skeleton_listener skelCord.cpp** (I got the code skelCord.cpp from this link http://answers.ros.org/question/230327/tf-listener-for-openni-tracker-solved/?comment=254098#post-id-254098, "skeleton_listener" is the name of the package). But when I try and run it I get the error

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named skelCord.cpp below /home/eric/catkin_ws/src/skeleton_listener
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/eric/catkin_ws/src/skeleton_listener/src/skelCord.cpp
```

If anyone knows why this error occurs their help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254104/unable-to-find-the-executable/) by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't directly run `.cpp` files, you'll have to compile them first. Probably as part of a package, in a catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on 2017-02-08**:
@gvdhoorn thank you for the answer, isn't compiling done using **catkin_make**, because I have already done catkin_make in the workspace.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-08**:
Ok. So what did you add to `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` in order to get the node to compile properly?

**Comment by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on 2017-02-08**:
@gvdhoorn I added this to the end of the Cmakelists.txt
**1. find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS std_msgs tf )
2. add_executable(skelCord src/skelCord.cpp)
3. target_link_libraries(skelCord ${catkin_LIBRARIES})**

I didn't add  to the package.xml  but its dependecies are std_msgs rospy roscpp

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-08**:
Ok. Then after `source`ing the `setup.bash`, you should be able to run:

```
rosrun skeleton_listener skelCord
```

Note that I didn't include the `.cpp` extension, as that is not included in the binary name in your `CMakeLists.txt` either.

**Comment by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on 2017-02-14**:
thank you that worked @gvdhoorn